# Jquery Datatables not updating values immediately

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

We have been working with Datatables for a while, but recently we came upon this problem where, after doing some calculations triggered by a blur event that is supposed to affect values in several rows of our table, some values are simply not displayed on screen immediately, requiring another blur (or perhaps waiting for another redraw?) to show on the page.

After researching about this online we decided to test the fnUpdate function. The problem is, that doesn't seem to work inside blur handlers. A sample code follows:

```
$('#myHtmlTable').on('blur', 'tbody td:nth-child(3)', function (e) {
    var table = $('#myDatatable').DataTable();
    //Iterate through the rows
    table.rows().every( function ( index, tableLoop, rowLoop ) {
        //gets the current row to work with
        var row = table.row(index);

        //do some calculations and come up with our values
        // ...
        //end of calculations

        //we tried it like this, didn't work
        row.field1 = value1;
        row.field2 = value2;
        row.field3 = value3;

        //alternatively we used fnUpdate like this to no effect
        //this throws an error that reads: "Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is no longer a child of this node. Perhaps it was moved in a 'blur' event handler?"
        $('#itensProdutoPrecoTable').dataTable().fnUpdate([value1, value2, value3], row.index())
    });
});
```

It looks like the table actually IS updated and our problem is with the rendering of the values. A draw() call also does nothing.

Comment: Which version of DataTable, you are using?

Comment: Using Editor 1.5.1

Comment: Have you tried to `destroy()` the table and then `draw`?